# jQuery not capturing change event from mobile Slider control

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a screen that performs a percent change calculation when the user adjusts the slider.

In its simplest form, it can be viewed here:  http://jsfiddle.net/4Bgx7/2608/

When I implement this code on my page, the calculation will only work if I insert an alert box.

This tells me something is wrong with my design, but I have not been able to pinpoint the problem.

The failing code is in a [text file here](http://www.o1solution.com/MyPage.html.txt).

Save it locally as "html" and open in a browser (IE, FF or Chrome)

When you click on the "Max Snapshot", you will be presented with the slider that doesn't work.

Close the browser and uncomment the following line:

```
//window.alert('uncomment me and I will work');
```

When you open the browser, click on "Max Snapshot", refresh the screen again and then click the slider.  It will work.

Comment the alert box line and save the file.  Refresh the page:  it will work.

Close the browser, rename the html file, open it:  it will not work.

Here is the html in case the links above do not work:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-rc.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
        <style media="screen" type="text/css">
            .number-block
            {
                text-align: right;
                padding-right: 2px;
            }

            .mobile-grid-header
            {
                background-color: darkgray;
                color: black;
                text-shadow:    none;
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            .original-value
            {
                /*visibility: hidden;
                position: absolute;*/
                color:red;
                background-color: yellow;
            }
    </style>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-rc.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function()
                  {
                      welcome_doc_ready();           
                  });

function welcome_doc_ready()
{
    //window.alert('uncomment me and I will work');
    $('#_singleRepMaxSlider').change(function() {
        var percentageValue    =    $('#_singleRepMaxSlider').val() / 100;
        $('.original-value').each(function () {
            var newValue = Math.floor(percentageValue * $(this).html());
            var checkDigit = newValue % 10;
            var newFactor = 0;
            //TODO:  Probably a bit overkill to round to nearest 5, but works
            switch(checkDigit)
            {
                case 0:
                case 1:
                case 2:
                case 3:
                    newFactor = 0;
                    break;
                case 4:
                case 5:
                case 6:
                    newFactor = 5;
                    break;
                case 7:
                case 8:
                case 9:
                    newFactor = 10;
                    break;
            }
            newValue    =    (Math.floor(newValue/10) * 10) + newFactor;
            $(this).next().html(newValue);
      });
    }
    );
}
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Start Main -->
        <div data-role="page" id="Main">
            <div data-role="header">
    </div>
            <!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="content">
                <p>
                    <a href="#MaxSnapshot" data-role="button">Max Snapshot</a>
                </p>
            </div>
            <!-- /content Main -->
            <div data-role="footer">
                <h4>Footer</h4>
            </div>
            <!-- /footer Main -->
        </div>
        <!-- /page Main-->
        <!-- MaxSnapshot -->
        <div data-role="page" id="MaxSnapshot">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Max Snapshot</h1>
                <a href="#Main" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse">Home</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="_singleRepMaxSlider">Change Single-Rep Max Percentage:</label>
                <input type="range" id="_singleRepMaxSlider" value="100" min="0" max="100" step="5"/>
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <p>
                    <h3>Single Rep Max</h3>
                    <div class="ui-grid-b" data-theme="e">
                        <div class="ui-block-a mobile-grid-header">
                            <b>Exercise</b>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ui-block-b mobile-grid-header">
                            <b>Lift Date</b>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ui-block-c  mobile-grid-header number-block">
                            <b>Weight(#)</b>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ui-block-a ">Back Squat</div>
                        <div class="ui-block-b ">9/19/2012</div>
                        <div class="ui-block-c   number-block">
                            <div class="original-value">185</div>
                            <div class="calculated-value">185</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ui-block-a alternate-row">Deadlift</div>
                        <div class="ui-block-b alternate-row">9/19/2012</div>
                        <div class="ui-block-c  alternate-row number-block">
                            <div class="original-value">205</div>
                            <div class="calculated-value">205</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ui-block-a ">Jerk Clean</div>
                        <div class="ui-block-b ">9/21/2012</div>
                        <div class="ui-block-c   number-block">
                            <div class="original-value">135</div>
                            <div class="calculated-value">135</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ui-block-a alternate-row">Shoulder Press</div>
                        <div class="ui-block-b alternate-row">9/19/2012</div>
                        <div class="ui-block-c  alternate-row number-block">
                            <div class="original-value">115</div>
                            <div class="calculated-value">115</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </p>
            </div>
            <a href="#Main" data-direction="reverse" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Return</a>
        </div>
        <!-- /page, MaxSnapshot -->
    </body>
</html>
```

---

## Update

I created a better example to reproduce this issue.  The answer to this problem is found [in the documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html):

> The first thing you learn in jQuery is to call code inside the
>   $(document).ready() function so everything will execute as soon as the
>   DOM is loaded. However, in jQuery Mobile, Ajax is used to load the
>   contents of each page into the DOM as you navigate, and the DOM ready
>   handler only executes for the first page. To execute code whenever a
>   new page is loaded and created, you can bind to the pageinit event.
>   This event is explained in detail at the bottom of this page.

Here is a more simplified example with solution commented out:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>

                //Bad Implementation:  This is what I originally had:
                $(document).ready(function()
                  {
                       //window.alert('uncomment me and I will work');
                        $('#_mainpageSlider').change(function() {
                            $('#_mainpageOutput').val($('#_mainpageSlider').val());
                        }
                        );
                        $('#_testpageSlider').change(function() {
                            $('#_testpageOutput').val($('#_testpageSlider').val());
                        }
                        );
                  });

                //Correct Implementation:  Comment or remove the above and uncomment the html below
                  /*($( '#TestPage' ).live( 'pageinit',function(event)
                  {
                        $('#_testpageSlider').change(function() {
                            $('#_testpageOutput').val($('#_testpageSlider').val());
                        }
                        );
                  });*/
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Start Main -->
        <div data-role="page" id="Main">
            <div data-role="header">
    </div>
            <!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="content">
                <p>
                    <a href="#TestPage" data-role="button">Test Page</a>
                </p>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="_mainpageSlider">Change Slider:</label>
                    <input type="range" id="_mainpageSlider" value="100" min="0" max="100" step="5"/>
                </div>
                <p>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="_mainpageSlider">Populate when Slider changes:</label>
                    <input id="_mainpageOutput" value=""/>
                </div>
                </p>
            </div>
            <!-- /content Main -->
            <div data-role="footer">
                <h4>Footer</h4>
            </div>
            <!-- /footer Main -->
        </div>
        <!-- /page Main-->
        <!-- TestPage -->
        <div data-role="page" id="TestPage">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Test Page</h1>
                <a href="#Main" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse">Home</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="_testpageSlider">Change Slider:</label>
                <input type="range" id="_testpageSlider" value="100" min="0" max="100" step="5"/>
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="_testpageOutput">Populate when Slider changes:</label>
                <input id="_testpageOutput" value=""/>
            </div>

            <a href="#Main" data-direction="reverse" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Return</a>
        </div>
        <!-- /page, TestPage -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have no problems with the slider (except in IE) you do how ever have a call to a (potentially) undefined function. Scriptwise you call the function before you define it. (You are saved because of the delay until the document is ready)

Comment: @RuneFS What OS are you on?  I reproduce this in both Windows 7 and Windows 8 Consumer Preview.

Comment: @RuneFS I also reproduce [this on my android browser](http://o1solution.com/m.html).  I'm surprised it works for you; but I suppose that's a good thing.

Comment: Odd behavior. It didn't work when I loaded it. I saw the exact behavior you explained. I turned on the alert and it worked. Turned the alert back off and started stepping through the code. It was working while I was stepping through the code. Turned off debug and did a hard refresh and the script is working fine now, with alert turned off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I think I've got it. The .ready() function is what is screwing you up. You should move all of your scripts to the end of your doc instead of the head and then call welcome_doc_ready() by using

```
$('#MaxSnapshot').live('pageinit',function(event){
    welcome_doc_ready();
});
```

instead of

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    welcome_doc_ready();           
});
```

Here, you're basically checking to make sure the Maxsnapshot div is good before you execute welcome_doc_ready(). Hope this helps.

Comment: After soaking this in I was able to find the [proper implementation](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html) on the jQuery Mobile site.  The example I had was not a good one because of the all the extra, unnecessary HTML.  It basically boiled down to replacing _.ready_ with _pageinit_; a solution I was able to find with your help. Ty.